# A basic real analysis question involving absolute value inequality

Tags: real-analysis

> Suppose $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $|x| < \varepsilon $ for all
> $\varepsilon > 0$. Please, prove $x = 0$.

#### Attempt:

If $x \neq 0 $, then assume $x > 0$. since $|x| < \varepsilon $ for all $\varepsilon$, we can pick $\varepsilon = x > 0$, then we have $|x| < x$, which is a contradiction.

On the other hand, if $x < 0$, then $-x > 0$ so pick $\varepsilon = - x $ and we have $|x| < - x $. Contradiction.

Is this enough of a proof?

Comment: Yup, looks fine to me.

Comment: Yes! To be a little "nicer", you can choose $\epsilon = \frac{x}{2}$, if $x  > 0$  and $\epsilon = \frac{-x}{2}$, if $x < 0$

Comment: Or avoid cases by choosing $\epsilon = |x|$.